# How do I redraw only portion of a GtkWidget

Tags: c, gtk, cairo

I want to redraw only part of a GtkTextView widget. In the draw signal handler I tried many things for example:

```
GdkRectangle rect;

gdk_cairo_get_clip_rectangle(cr, &rect);

cairo_surface_t* surface = cairo_get_target(cr);
cairo_surface_t* newsurf = cairo_surface_create_similar(surface, cairo_surface_get_content(surface), rect.width - 50, rect.height);

cairo_push_group(cr);
cairo_set_source_surface(cr, newsurf, rect.x + 10, rect.y + 40);
cairo_fill_preserve(cr);
cairo_stroke(cr);
cairo_pop_group_to_source(cr);
cairo_paint(cr);
```

except that nothing really happens. How do I re-draw only a rect of the dirty clip region in `cr` or how (as I am trying) to modify `cr` so that the surface area has different dimensions?

---

To clarify further - I don't draw my own things. I want to set my own surface in the cairo_t passed in the draw callback of the GtkTextView for greater control of how the widget is rendered naturally. This new surface may be the same as the source surface in `cr`, but cropped or an earlier "snapshot" of the widget obtained with `gtk_widget_draw()`

Comment: Why do you want to redraw only part of a widget? In general, your code should always be able to redraw the full widget. Also, by the time the drawing code runs, the background was most likely already drawn, so the old content is gone. Your example code seems to try to copy the old content...?

Comment: @UliSchlachter Yes it does. Assume I have the widget drawn in cairo_t at some point. I want to later draw it on top of the widget so that it seems like it restored previous state. My code tries to change the surface of the cairo_t passed in draw signal handler.

Comment: Well... what your code does is to create two new, empty surfaces (one explicitly, one implicitly as a group). One is set as the source for drawing to the other. Then it does nothing (filling and stroking and empty path). Finally, it draws the group (which is still an empty surface, so most likely fully transparent) to the actual drawing target. I do not really know what you mean with "tries to change the surface". Where should the content for drawing come from?

Comment: @UliSchlachter How are both empty? `cr` as passed from the draw signal handler should contain widget area to be redrawn.

Comment: I changed the code to do what I want to achieve in another way and I have a cairo_t containing a snapshot of the widget obtained with `gtk_widget_draw` and I would want to draw that on the widget when it is supposed to re-draw itself in the draw signal handler, but I have no idea how to do it. I tried setting `cr`'s source as it is in the code here above, but nothing happens.

Comment: Empty in the sense: All pixels are transparent. Not empty in the sense of "empty area".

Comment: A cr (well, `cairo_t`) does not contain any images. A cairo surface does. So, if I understand you correctly: You want to create a separate cairo surface (e.g. via `cairo_image_surface_create`) and draw your content to that. Now you can just copy that surface to other surfaces via `cairo_set_source_surface` and `cairo_paint`. Right? (Or: What do you mean with "a snapshot of the widget"? Since you are drawing the widget yourself, you already should have the widget's content, shouldn't you?)

Comment: @UliSchlachter Yes you understand correctly for the first. But no I don't draw the widget myself! I connect a draw signal handler on a GtkTextView (a GtkSourceView actually). At some point I call gtk_widget_draw() to save how the widget looked at this point and the function returns a cairo_t. Later on I want to draw that cairo_t (its surface as you mentioned) on the GtkTextView so that it looks as it is in its old state.

Comment: That way I can make GtkTextView display earlier states of good text alongside new text, even if the textbuffer is empty or contains different data.

Comment: `At some point I call gtk_widget_draw() to save how the widget looked at this point and the function returns a cairo_t. ` I do not see `gtk_widget_draw()` returning a `cairo_t*`. According to the API docs, you give a `cairo_t*` to this function when you call it, and the widget is then drawn to that cairo context. So, if you want to get a screenshot of a widget, you have to create a new cairo surface (e.g. `cairo_image_surface_create()`), create a cairo context for this (`cairo_create()`) and call `gtk_widget_draw`. Now, the widget is drawn to your surface.

Comment: @UliSchlachter Yep, I already do that. I know it works, because I've exported it to png. I created the cairo_t and the surface with the dimensions of the allocated width/height of the widget.

Comment: Sorry, but then I still fail to understand the question. If you have a `cairo_surface_t`, you can draw it to the widget via `cairo_set_source_surface` and `cairo_paint`.

Comment: @UliSchlachter Correct. At least I tried so, but nothing happens. The widget is not updated. Nothing happens.

Comment: Try `cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 0, 0); cairo_paint(cr);`. If the widget does not become completely red, then the problem is somewhere around your "intercept the drawing of the widget"-code. You could open a new question related to that (but I would kind of expect people to tell you that you should not mess with the drawing of widgets like that).